# add value to sublist

Tags: python, list

If I have the data look like

```
data = [[['a','A'],['b','B']],
[['c','C'],['d','D']]]
data2 = [['1','2'],
['3','4']]
```

Is it possible to make the result look like

```
result = [[['a','A','1'],['b','B','2']],
[['c','C','3'],['d','D','4']]]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
result = [[x+[y] for x,y in zip(a,b)]
          for a,b in zip(data, data2)]
```

Output:

```
[[['a', 'A', '1'], ['b', 'B', '2']], [['c', 'C', '3'], ['d', 'D', '4']]]
```